# Sharing folder in Virtualbox

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine, file-sharing

I'm running Debian 9 as Host and I installed correctly Windows 7 as guest by using Oracle VirtualBox (v. 5.2.6); both the OSs work fine and I need to have a folder shared between those 2 operative systems.

In order to be able to get this, I followed these steps:

1. *GuestAddition* installation, by running, as super-user:

   apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11 linux-headers-$(uname -r)
2. Creating the candidate folder `/home/quant/Scrivania/VirtualBox/Data` by modifying the Oracle VirtualBox Manager settings (Shared Folders);
3. mounting the device by running:

   mount -t vboxsf Data /home/quant/Scrivania/VirtualBox/Data/

At the point (3), I got the following **error message** in the **terminal**:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

It seems like the folder does not exist although I manually create the local folder and set it as shared folder in the VirtualBox manager.

Someone could suggest a solution?

Hope I has been clear when I asked the question. Thanks you all in advice!

Comment: For a sanity check, are the VirtualBox modules loaded (check `lsmod|grep vbox`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply solved by following those steps; first of all install Oracle Virtual Box as follows:

1. run as super-user `nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`
2. paste `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib` and after type `ctrl+O` and `ctrl+X` to save and quit respectively
3. run from the terminal:

   - `wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | apt-key add -`
   - `apt update`
   - `apt-get install virtualbox-5.2`
   - `apt-get install dkms`

After, download the .iso image from the *[Oracle Repository](https://blogs.oracle.com/joshis/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso-download)* and choosing the version you need on the basis of your host OS and install *GuestAdditions* by selecting from the virtual machine window menu

> *Device > Insert ISO image for GuestAdditions*

and follow what suggested by the installation guide. Finally, go through

> *Devices > Shared Folder*

and select the path in which is contained the folder you need to share.

Answer (score 2):

Your error: `/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device` could be caused because you are mounting the SF with the same name for the share and mount point. They should be different (i.e share is called `~/share` and mount point `~/host`) You will also need to make sure you have followed these [steps correctly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders):

> - Create a folder on the Host computer (ubuntu) that you would like to share, for example ~/share
> - Boot the Guest operating system in VirtualBox.
> - Select Devices -> Shared Folders...
> - Choose the 'Add' button.
> - Select ~/share
> - Optionally select the 'Make permanent' option

After you have completed that process, open your terminal on the host and run:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) /home/quant/Scrivania/VirtualBox/Data ~/host
```

(`/home/quant/Scrivania/VirtualBox/Data` and `~/host` may have to be reversed or changed to the appropriate names)
If that step completes successfully on your Windows guest you should be able to run:

`net use x: \\vboxsvr\[whatever your share folder's name is]`

Keep your shared folder name simple such as `~/Data` or `~/share` instead of `/home/quant/Scrivania/VirtualBox/Data` as that may be another source for your issue. Good Luck!